# Preposition-usage in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

Should I say:

> It's a book I need to make a summary
>
> It's a book I need to make a summary **about**
>
> It's a book I need to make a summary **about it**

Which one is the most correct? And how can I know whether or not I should use a preposition?
For example: should I use **in** at the end of this sentence?

> I love the world I live

Comment: Most people would say *a book I need to make a summary **of*** (unless they went for the verb form *a book I need to **summarise***). And it's *the world I live **in*** (or *the world **in which** I live*).

Comment: The first sentence means “In order to make a summary (of something else), I need to use that book.”